# why is this function firing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that fires when a user pastes into the textarea.  I have a timed function that fires inside this function so that the function can get the text in the textarea that the user pastes.

My problem is that in safari, this function fires twice each time and I cant work out why.

```
function Func1(){

    var valu = $('#thoughts').val();
    $(function () { 

        $.post("paste.php", { uid: $('#uid').val(), paste: $('#thoughts').val()},function(data){

            $('#pasteditems').prepend($(data).hide().fadeIn(1300));

        });

    });

    $('#thoughts').css('background','#FFFFFF');
    $('#thoughts').css("color","#AAD1ED");
    $('#thoughts').css("font-size","90px");
    $('#thoughts').val("");    

}

function OnPaste(){

    $('#thoughts').css("font-size","18px");
    $('#thoughts').css('background','#EEEEEE');
    setTimeout("Func1()", 0800);

}
```

html

```
<textarea onblur='self.focus' wrap="physical" onpaste="OnPaste ()" id="thoughts" name="thoughts"></textarea>
```

Comment: Have you considered indenting your code?

Comment: `setTimeout("Func1()", 0800);` has two problems: 1) passing astring is bad, use `func1` without quotes or parens. 2) 0800 is an octal number but since it contains 8 it's invalid

Comment: still not working with these answers, I took the quotes off and tried the third answer and it is still firing twice.  Changed the time to 1000 instead of 800 also.

Comment: Just to make sure the problem isn't upstream, make sure you're not calling `setTimeout` (via `OnPaste`) twice for some reason.

Comment: its something to do with the keypress I think, because if I remove the setTimeout and just have the Func1(); it still fires twice without the text pasted through the textarea.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
setTimeout(Func1, 800);
```

Safari may be evaluating that function when it reads through that code the first time, since you have the parentheses on it.

Comment: No it may not since it's inside a string. But using a function instead of a string is better anyway.

Comment: I took the quotes off and tried the third answer and it is still firing twice. Changed the time to 1000 instead of 800 also.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `setTimeout` Function:

```
setTimeout(Func1, 0800);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way around

```
setTimeout(function(){ Func1(); }, 800);
```